# How to write a to a text file from SQL Server Stored Procedure running on Docker Container on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, t-sql

So we have a SQL Server database running in a Docker Container on Linux

There is a stored procedure which will take in JSON as a parameter and extracts data out into a table called dbo.BCPOutput defined as follows:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[BCPOutput]
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BCPOutput](
        [JobNumber] [int] NULL,
        [CSVLine] [nvarchar](2000) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[BCPOutput] ([JobNumber], [CSVLine]) VALUES (NULL, N'21.34,2023-12-05T10:36:29')
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[BCPOutput] ([JobNumber], [CSVLine]) VALUES (NULL, N'14.04,2023-12-05T10:36:29')
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[BCPOutput] ([JobNumber], [CSVLine]) VALUES (NULL, N'38.96,2023-12-05T10:36:29')
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[BCPOutput] ([JobNumber], [CSVLine]) VALUES (NULL, N'14.62,2023-12-05T10:36:29')
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[BCPOutput] ([JobNumber], [CSVLine]) VALUES (NULL, N'16.52,2023-11-22T16:41:29')
    GO
```

Now I can run this from SQL Server Management Studio (in SQLCMD mode)

```
:connect 217CAS -U sa -P xxxxxxx
:SETVAR DatabaseName Metrology 
 :OUT /data/readings/Data.csv 
 use Metrology;
 select csvline from dbo.bcpOutput
```

But I want to be able to execute this code in my stored procedure

This code was working on windows...but we were able to use xp_cmdshell which only runs on windows

Also FYI i dont have access the docker container or the linux VM to run stuff from the command line

So it all has to be done from a stored procedure
So how can I write to a text file on my local drive from a stored procedure running on docker container on Linux?

Comment: SQL Server isn't designed for exporting the data; instead have something *connect* to SQL Server and export that data. Using `xp_cmdshell` (to do something like call `bcp`, to reconnect the the server that invoked the command line, to export the data) is a crutch and quirky feature that you just *shouldn't* be using in the first place. Bash/Powershell would be *far* better methods.

Comment: _Also FYI i dont have access the docker container or the linux VM to run stuff from the command line._ Of course you do, `docker exec -it b04c8e794c83 /bin/bash`. Substitute `b04c8e794c83` with your own container's id as output from `docker container ls`.

Comment: @ThomA More the point: it's not even going to work at all using `xp_cmdshell`. OP wants it written to the *local* drive, which SQL Server cannot do directly. Only a tool on the *local* machine such as SQLCMD or SSMS can do this.

Comment: @ThomA i dont know much about Bash..but can it be used to extract data from the SQL Server and writing to a file?

Comment: Just run `sqlcmd` from Bash on your local machine.

Comment: @Charlieface `xp_cmdshell` doesn't work on SQL Server on Linux, period; it's listed as one of the unsupported features. If it *did* however, the OP could use it to write to the (docker) host, if they mounted a directory on the host to the container.